# Is Rails time broken for midnight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time, timezone, utc

Let's look at the date:

```
1.9.2p320 :008 > Date.today
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 
1.9.2p320 :009 > Time.now
 => 2012-10-03 22:32:55 -0400
```

Now, given that when is midnight?

```
1.9.2p320 :005 > Date.today.midnight
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Makes sense. But what about yesterday?

```
1.9.2p320 :006 > Date.yesterday.midnight
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Uh, that doesn't quite make sense. Midnight today is the same as midnight yesterday? You can't be serious!

```
1.9.2p320 :026 > Date.today.midnight == Date.yesterday.midnight
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :033 > 1.day.ago.midnight == Date.yesterday.midnight
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :034 > 1.day.ago.midnight == Date.today.midnight
 => true
```

Oh, you are serious. What about tomorrow?

```
1.9.2p320 :007 > Date.tomorrow.midnight
 => Fri, 05 Oct 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Wait, if midnight today is 00:00 on the 3rd, and midnight yesterday is 00:00 on the 3th, but midnight tomorrow is 00:00 on the 5th, where's 00:00 on the 4th?

Here it is:

```
1.9.2p320 :010 > 0.days.ago
 => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 02:34:58 UTC +00:00 
1.9.2p320 :011 > 0.days.ago.midnight
 => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

but isn't zero days ago *today?* Apparently not.

Is it me, or is this not at all internally consistent? It seem to me that Date.today should be the same as 0.days.ago.

I understand that `days.ago` is actually using the Time object, and that this is a time zone issue:

```
1.9.2p320 :030 > Date.today
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 
1.9.2p320 :021 > Time.now
 => 2012-10-03 22:40:09 -0400 
1.9.2p320 :023 > 0.days.ago
 => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 02:40:22 UTC +00:00 
1.9.2p320 :022 > Time.zone.now
 => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 02:40:14 UTC +00:00
```

But it seems as though, given that these are convenience functions, it's kind of mean to throw a timezone assumption into *one* convenience function and not throw it into *another* convenience function, both of which, by all accounts, mean the same thing.

Even setting that aside, it doesn't seem to explain the fact that `Date.today.midnight == Date.yesterday.midnight`, which is– quite simply– barking mad.

Since I know that I can't be the first to have been bitten by this, I ask *what am I missing?*

Answer (score 8):

Rails will base relative date calculations such as `yesterday`, `tomorrow`, and `midnight` off of `Date.current` which will attempt to use the configured `Time.zone`:  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L46

Since your `Time.zone` is set to UTC, you won't get the same results as calculations based off `Date.today`, which will use your computer's clock time, unless you're actually sitting in UTC time.

So, if the time difference between you and UTC is greater than the time to midnight, `Date.yesterday` and `Date.today` actually return the same date!

Try setting your Rails time zone with `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` or whatever time zone you're in and retry your examples.

Comment: Note also that `0.days.ago` is a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, while `Date.today` gives you a `Date`. If you care about time zones, use timestamps everywhere. If you care about dates, use dates. If you want to tear your hair out, mix them by calling `#midnight` and such.

Comment: Right. So maybe the short answer to the original question is, 'Yes, completely broken.'

Comment: An alternative short answer is "No, you're using it wrong". Timekeeping is remarkably complex. (Constantly changing time zone offsets, [time zones beyond UTC +/- 12 hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_UTC_offset#UTC.2B12:45.2C_M.E2.80.A0), [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), or how [time elapsed depends on jurisdiction](http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/epochtime.html).) Converting between dates and times without understanding the mechanisms involved is going to hurt.

Comment: This is true, and I understand that, but it doesn't explain the internal inconsistency between `Date.today` and `Date.yesterday`. My expectation– what would be my argument– is that those should be consistent within the timezone, whether UTC or another.

Comment: I did explain the reason for the inconsistency that you observed.

Comment: `Date.today` and `Date.yesterday` are consistent -- using date math against the Ruby interpreter's global time zone, inherited from libc. This is different than the Rails timezone machinery, which you invoke when you say `#midnight`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3831426) for a demonstration.

Comment: @rossta Poorly worded comment on my part. I meant to say something more like "it seems wrong use two different strategies to calculate the results from such similarly named methods." Your comment does explain the reason, but I was more looking for "the reasoning." willglynn fills in the rest, though.

Answer (score 1):

[rossta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719804/17410) identified the culprit. You may have better luck with `Time.now.to_date` and specifying the time zone if necessary:

```
> Time.now.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo")
  => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 12:54:43 JST +09:00 
> Time.now.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").to_date.midnight
 => Thu, 04 Oct 2012 00:00:00 JST +09:00 
Time.now.in_time_zone("Asia/Tokyo").to_date.yesterday.midnight
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 00:00:00 JST +09:00 

> Time.zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
 => "America/Los_Angeles" 
> Time.now.in_time_zone
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 20:55:35 PDT -07:00 

> Time.now.to_date # using the system time
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 
> Time.now.to_date.midnight
 => Wed, 03 Oct 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00 
> Time.now.to_date.yesterday.midnight
 => Tue, 02 Oct 2012 00:00:00 PDT -07:00
```